# Displaying complex numbers in java

Tags: java, string, methods, double

My goal today is to be able to add, subtract, multiply and divide complex numbers (a+bi) and show that data somehow. I knew the difficult would arise when I tried to create a method that divides complex numbers. It should display approximately 0.39189-.1486i if my math is correct or ((29-11i)/74). The output I get is: -0.041666666666666664+0.4583333333333333i , which is incorrect.

Can you help me find the error in the ComplexDiv method?

Here is the code:

```
public String ComplexDiv(ComplexNumbers other) {

        String r = Double.toString(((real*other.real)-(complex*other.complex))
                / ((other.real * other.real)-(other.complex * other.complex)));

        String c = Double.toString((-(real*other.complex)+(other.real*complex)) 
                / ((other.real * other.real)-(other.complex * other.complex)));

        return r + "+" + c + "i";
    }
```

Here is the testing class to call that method:

```
public class ComplexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComplexNumbers c1 = new ComplexNumbers();
        ComplexNumbers c2 = new ComplexNumbers();

        c1.real = 3;
        c1.complex = 2;
        c2.real = 5;
        c2.complex = 7;

        System.out.println(c1.ComplexAdd(c2));
        System.out.println(c1.ComplexSub(c2));
        System.out.println(c1.ComplexMult(c2));
        System.out.println(c1.ComplexDiv(c2));
        System.out.println(c1.findConjugate());
    }
}
```

Bonus question: Any idea how I could represent my answers in a fraction form instead of a decimal?

Here is the entire ComplexNumbers Class just to give you an overview of my approach:

```
package exerciseslearningjava;

public class ComplexNumbers {

    public double real;
    public double complex;
    public double realConvert;
    public double compConvert;


    public String ComplexAdd(ComplexNumbers other) {

        String r = Double.toString(real + other.real);
        String c = Double.toString(complex + other.complex);

        return r + "+" + c + "i";
    }
    public String ComplexSub(ComplexNumbers other) {

        String r = Double.toString(real - other.real);
        String c = Double.toString(complex - other.complex);

        return r + c + "i";
    }
    public String ComplexMult(ComplexNumbers other) {

        String r = Double.toString((real * other.real) - (complex*other.complex));
        String c = Double.toString((real * other.complex)+(complex*other.real));

        return r + "+" + c + "i";

    }
    public String ComplexDiv(ComplexNumbers other) {

        String r = Double.toString(((real*other.real)-(complex*other.complex))
                / ((other.real * other.real)-(other.complex * other.complex)));

        String c = Double.toString((-(real*other.complex)+(other.real*complex)) 
                / ((other.real * other.real)-(other.complex * other.complex)));

        return r + "+" + c + "i";
    }
    public String findConjugate() {
        String r = Double.toString(real);
        String c = Double.toString(complex);

        return r + "-" + c + "i";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your denominator:

```
((other.real * other.real) - (other.complex * other.complex))
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
((other.real * other.real) + (other.complex * other.complex))
```

Since you get this by multiplying a complex number by its conjugate:

```
(a + bi) * (a - bi) = (a * a) - (b * b * i * i)
```

But since `i * i` is -1, this becomes:

```
(a + bi) * (a - bi) = (a * a) + (b * b)
```

Also, as an aside, I get bad feelings in the back of my neck when I see Strings being used to represent numeric values. Why use Strings? Why not float or BigDecimal?

Comment: no because of the conjugate. (r2+c2)(r2-c2) = r2^2 - c2^2

Comment: @BrettCunninghamII: Are you sure? Please see explanation in answer.

Comment: @BrettCunninghamII: and see [Wikipedia article on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Multiplication_and_division) which supports my answer.

Comment: i have to go to work that's why I threw this question up there. But to answer you question i didn't know how to display complex numbers without the String because if you wrote a +bi and a and b are ints or doubles then java would add them together. I used strings to keep things separate and display in it on the screen.

Comment: @BrettCunninghamII: don't confuse display of a number with the internal storage of a number. Have methods for display, but do not internally represent the numbers as Strings or use Strings in your equations. That's dangerous business.